# How to return the result of a dialog question in a bash function

Tags: bash, dialog, sh, kdialog

I tried to return the result of a question asked from the `dialog` command.
But when I tried that, it freeze and when I press an arrow or enter, it clear the screen, and I just see  `: numerical argument nessecary`. I think it's an error throw by `return`, but I don't no why?
That is not an error from Dialog, because the same command without the `return` work.

```
function BUL_askYesNo()
{
        return $(dialog --yesno "$1" 0 0)
}
```

I tried with KDialog, and it work, so I don't know what is the probleme with Dialog...

Comment: Note that after I've got this error, when I click, it add the click char code to the command prompt

Comment: How do you run your function BUL_askYesNo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `dialog` in command substitution `$()`, the stdout is not terminal any more.

You need to pass it to `dialog` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function BUL_askYesNo()
{   
    exec 3>&1
    return $(dialog --yesno "$1" 0 0 2>&1 1>&3)
}
BUL_askYesNo Hello
```

But `return` is still not working. I think this is much simpler :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function BUL_askYesNo()
{   
    dialog --yesno "$1" 0 0
}
BUL_askYesNo Hello
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!